# Combining fields in one table into one field in another table in Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access-2007

I am trying to combine multiple fields from one table that has user id and 10 columns of data arranged horizontally to be displayed in two fields vertically having one field corresponding to the User ID and another corresponding to the 10 vertical fields.  In the second table User name would be repeated for the number of times that there are inputs in the 10 horizontal fields in the original table.

My example is basically:

``````
MainT
`````
User ID
otherfields
Invoice1
:
Invoice10
``````

Wanting to put into new table:

``````````
InvoicesT
`````````
User ID
Invoices
``````````

I need to know how to get the data from MainT:

```
User    |   Othr Fld    |   Invoice1    |   Invoice2    |   Invoice3
--------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------
1       |   JF          |   Paid        |   Past Due    |  Civil Court
2       |   JN          |   Paid        |   Paid        |  Past Due
3       |   MO          |   Past Due    |   Paid        |  Paid
```

to populate into InvoicesT in the manner which I have prescribed.

```
User    |   Invoice
--------+--------------
1       |   Paid
1       |   Past Due 
1       |   Civil Court
2       |   Paid
2       |   Past Due
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall having one simple query that can transform the data like the way you want it. The first thing that came to my mind was a Crosstab Query, however this is not something you can do using the data structure you have. I would like to give you a VBA solution, as I feel you are going on the right track in redesigning your table data.

For this solution to work, first create the second table `InvoicesT`, with the following fields.

``````````
InvoicesT
`````````
Field Name          |   Data Type
--------------------+------------------
invoiceID           |   Autonumber 
UserID              |   Number
InvoiceCategory     |   Text
``````````

Next, you copy the following Sub into a Standard Module.

```
Public Sub transferData()
    Dim oldTbl As DAO.Recordset, newTbl As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database
    Dim fCtr As Integer

    Set dbObj = CurrentDB()

    'Open the MainT table to read the information.
    Set oldTbl = dbObj.OpenRecordSet("SELECT [User ID], Invoice1, Invoice2, Invoice3, Invoice4, " & _
                                     "Invoice5, Invoice6, Invoice7, Invoice8, Invoice9, Invoice10 FROM MainT")

    'Open the InvoicesT to write new information into.
    Set newTbl = dbObj.OpenRecordSet("InvoicesT")

    'Loop through the list of all entries in MainT
    Do While Not oldTbl.EOF
        'This will loop through the fields to create one entry for each field.
        'You can change the number 10 to any number depending on the Invoice fields in the table. 
        For fCtr = 1 To 10
            'I have put an IF condition to make sure there are not many empty records for a UserID
            'If the Invoice(n) is not available for a particular user, then it does not create an entry. 
            If Len(oldTbl.Fields("Invoice" & fCtr) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
                With newTbl
                    .AddNew
                    .Fields("UserID") = oldTbl.Fields(0)
                    .Fields("InvoiceCategory") = oldTbl.Fields("Invoice" & fCtr)
                    .Update
                End With
            End If
        Next
        'Go to the next record when one user is done with
        oldTbl.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Clean up
    Set newTbl = Nothing
    Set oldTbl = Nothing
    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now once you have saved the Module with a name like `mod_TransferTables` and compiled it. Go to your immediate window (CTRL + G). Then simply type `transferData` and hit `ENTER`, it might take a while based on the number of records in the `MainT` table. Once this is complete. You should be having all the data in the new table.

Hope this helps !

Comment: It is hanging up on this:

et oldTbl = dbObj.OpenRecordSet("SELECT [User ID], Invoice1, Invoice2, Invoice3, Invoice4, " & _
                                     "Invoice5, Invoice6, Invoice7, Invoice8, Invoice9, Invoice10 FROM MainT")

It is calling the underscore a illegal or unrecognized character.  

Is the ampersand and underscore necessary or can the series continue with commas?

Comment: You can just carry on in one long string, it is just easier to read with `& _ ` that's all. Try this. `Set oldTbl = dbObj.OpenRecordSet("SELECT [User ID], Invoice1, Invoice2, Invoice3, Invoice4, Invoice5, Invoice6, Invoice7, Invoice8, Invoice9, Invoice10 FROM MainT")`